# Unable to symbolicate from required binary CoreLocation.framework on XCode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, crash, dsym

I was trying to symbolicate crash log but i have got below error message. If any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Error message is

```
 ## Warning: Unable to symbolicate from required binary: /Users/ramkrishna/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/11.2 (15C5110b)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
```

Crash Logs

```
 Incident Identifier: 2BFCFCD8-7B7F-434D-B9FF-5B4577AA37E4
    CrashReporter Key:   4e3a111248afeb9fe9595b89dd38c506ed484f8a
    Hardware Model:      iPad5,3
    Process:             FlightCrew [320]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F26370FC-79F0-4090-BBB0-D8B87AF74D56/FlightCrew.app/FlightCrew
    Identifier:          com.sas.wefly.qa
    Version:             2.4.0.65 DEBUG CR-WU (2.4)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Role:                Non UI
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    Coalition:           com.sas.wefly.qa [459]


    Date/Time:           2018-08-06 15:47:34.4273 +0530
    Launch Time:         2018-08-03 18:05:14.4913 +0530
    OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2 (15C5110b)
    Baseband Version:    n/a
    Report Version:      104

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Application Specific Information:
    abort() called

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Last Exception Backtrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                  0x18515a364 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1843a0528 objc_exception_throw + 55
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x18515a2ac +[NSException raise:format:] + 115
    3   FlightCrew                      0x10098846c +[WLCertManager generateKeyPair:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:] + 4424812 (WLCertManager.m:224)
    4   FlightCrew                      0x10098c6fc +[WLCertManager signJWSPartsWithPayload:withPrivateKeyLabel:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:] + 4441852 (WLCertManager.m:475)
    5   FlightCrew                      0x10096e724 -[WLAuthorizationManager buildJWSPartsWithClientId:] + 4319012 (WLAuthorizationManager.m:896)
    6   FlightCrew                      0x100954980 __71-[WLRequest addClientInstanceIdHeaderWithRequest:withCompetionHandler:]_block_invoke + 4213120 (WLRequest.m:276)
    7   FlightCrew                      0x100969c7c -[WLAuthorizationManager clientInstanceIdWithCompletionHandler:] + 4299900 (WLAuthorizationManager.m:510)
    8   FlightCrew                      0x100954830 -[WLRequest addClientInstanceIdHeaderWithRequest:withCompetionHandler:] + 4212784 (WLRequest.m:270)
    9   FlightCrew                      0x10095386c -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] + 4208748 (WLRequest.m:246)
    10  FlightCrew                      0x100955160 -[WLRequest makeRequest:withOptions:withCallback:] + 4215136 (WLRequest.m:331)
    11  FlightCrew                      0x100954bf8 -[WLRequest makeRequest:withOptions:] + 4213752 (WLRequest.m:299)
    12  FlightCrew                      0x10098f6cc -[WLClient sendHeartBeat] + 4454092 (WLClient.m:230)
    13  Foundation                      0x185b7a5b8 __NSFireTimer + 87
    14  CoreFoundation                  0x185102fc0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    15  CoreFoundation                  0x185102ce4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 863
    16  CoreFoundation                  0x1851024e4 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 247
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x1851000cc __CFRunLoopRun + 1927
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x18501fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 435
    19  GraphicsServices                0x186eecf84 GSEventRunModal + 99
    20  UIKit                           0x18e6c08c8 UIApplicationMain + 235
    21  FlightCrew                      0x1006e6b9c main + 1665948 (AppDelegate.swift:57)
    22  libdyld.dylib                   0x184b3c56c start + 3


    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c6c2e8 __pthread_kill + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d812f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184bdb060 __abort + 152
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000184bdafc8 __abort + 0
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000184377068 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
    5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000184377210 default_unexpected_handler+ 8720 () + 0
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001843a0810 _objc_terminate+ 34832 () + 124
    7   FlightCrew                      0x0000000100871208 CLSTerminateHandler+ 3281416 () + 344
    8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018438f54c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 107852 ()) + 16
    9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018438f158 __cxa_rethrow + 144
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001843a06e8 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018501fec4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544
    12  GraphicsServices                0x0000000186eecf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
    13  UIKit                           0x000000018e6c08c8 UIApplicationMain + 236
    14  FlightCrew                      0x00000001006e6b9c main + 1665948 (AppDelegate.swift:57)
    15  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000184b3c56c start + 4

    Thread 1 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b3e0 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185102308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ffed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018501fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    5   Foundation                      0x0000000185a77594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
    6   Foundation                      0x0000000185a969ac -[NSRunLoop+ 178604 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
    7   UIKit                           0x000000018f22a7e8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
    8   Foundation                      0x0000000185b790f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 2 name:  com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b3e0 mach_msg + 72
    2   FlightCrew                      0x000000010085e488 CLSMachExceptionServer + 100
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b3e0 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185102308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ffed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018501fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    5   Foundation                      0x0000000185a77594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
    6   FlightCrew                      0x000000010093d4ac -[CallbackExecutor threadMain] + 4117676 (CallbackExecutor.m:62)
    7   Foundation                      0x0000000185b790f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 4 name:  AFNetworking
    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b3e0 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185102308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ffed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018501fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    5   Foundation                      0x0000000185a77594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
    6   Foundation                      0x0000000185ac956c -[NSRunLoop+ 386412 (NSRunLoop) run] + 88
    7   FlightCrew                      0x00000001008cc838 +[WLAFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 3655736 (WLAFURLConnectionOperation.m:178)
    8   Foundation                      0x0000000185b790f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b3e0 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185102308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ffed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018501fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018590e718 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 780
    6   Foundation                      0x0000000185b790f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c6c0f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d82ce4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
    2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000184322ea4 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 32420 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
    3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c481b58 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >+ 9726808 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 96
    4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c481a80 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop+ 9726592 () + 172
    5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018c481de4 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >+ 9727460 (void*) + 44
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 7 name:  WebThread
    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b3e0 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185102308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ffed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018501fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    5   WebCore                         0x000000018cf4e2c8 RunWebThread+ 266952 (void*) + 560
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFNetwork.CustomProtocols
    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b3e0 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185102308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ffed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018501fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018590e718 -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 780
    6   Foundation                      0x0000000185b790f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 9 name:  NetworkLoad
    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b568 mach_msg_trap + 8
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b3e0 mach_msg + 72
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185102308 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ffed4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018501fe58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
    5   GeoServices                     0x000000018b2740ec _runNetworkThread + 468
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d802b4 _pthread_body + 308
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d80180 _pthread_body + 0
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb74 thread_start + 4

    Thread 10:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c6cd80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eeec _pthread_wqthread + 884
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb6c start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 11:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb68 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 12:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c6cd80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7f080 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb6c start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 13:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c6cd80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eeec _pthread_wqthread + 884
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb6c start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 14 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c0120f00.events
    Thread 14:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000184c4b5bc semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ad9000 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 84
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ad9870 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
    3   CoreLocation                    0x000000018b75d554 0x18b75a000 + 13652
    4   CoreLocation                    0x000000018b762fe8 0x18b75a000 + 36840
    5   CoreLocation                    0x000000018b762d18 0x18b75a000 + 36120
    6   CoreLocation                    0x000000018b7bad98 0x18b75a000 + 396696
    7   CoreLocation                    0x000000018b7b716c 0x18b75a000 + 381292
    8   CoreLocation                    0x000000018b7b7090 0x18b75a000 + 381072
    9   CoreLocation                    0x000000018b7b8924 0x18b75a000 + 387364
    10  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000184dba634 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
    11  libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000184db7fc8 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 984
    12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ad6ae4 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
    13  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184aed454 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 356
    14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ae0824 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
    15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184aee0d0 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 952
    16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ae0824 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
    17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ae12fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
    18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ae0824 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
    19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ae12fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
    20  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184ae1d20 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 404
    21  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184aea03c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7ef1c _pthread_wqthread + 932
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb6c start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 15:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb68 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 16:
    0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184d7eb68 start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
        x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
        x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
        x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000000003
       x12: 0xffffffffffffffff  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000184bf153f  x15: 0x0000000000000010
       x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000000ffffffff  x18: 0xfffffff00829925c  x19: 0x0000000000000006
       x20: 0x00000001b5ecbb80  x21: 0x000000016f8af490  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b5ecbc60
       x24: 0x00000001c00128b0  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
       x28: 0x000000016f8afb38   fp: 0x000000016f8af3b0   lr: 0x0000000184d812f8
        sp: 0x000000016f8af380   pc: 0x0000000184c6c2e8 cpsr: 0x00000000
```